# Filter rows according to a string match, when i am unsure of specific column

Tags: sql, database, oracle, filter, row

Can someone help me on SQL Query to filter rows according to a string.

Consider i want to display all rows which contains a string = 'PARIS'. No speicific column to mention. Need filtering at entire row level.

Is it possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you need to search all of the columns of a particular table whose columns you know, or of any given table whose columns you must determine at run time? Are you familiar with the `LIKE` operator? In any case, it is possible, but you will find the community here more helpful if you show some more effort at a solution yourself.

Comment: Yes, even i am unsure of how many columns in that table and what are column names.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is possible indeed, you can have **multiple conditions in your `WHERE` clause** and link them with `OR`.

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable
    WHERE yourtable.column1 = 'yourstring'
        OR yourtable.column2 = 'yourstring'
```

This will return all rows from table `yourtable` where `column1` or `column2` is equal to `yourstring`. You can expand this to as many columns as you need.

Note that if you want to look for fields that *contain* your string, you have to use the `LIKE` syntax with wildcards:

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable
    WHERE yourtable.column1 LIKE '%yourstring%'
        OR yourtable.column2 LIKE '%yourstring%'
```

**Edit:** If you **do not know up front which columns are in your table**, the only way to solve this that I am aware of would be to fetch the column names using [`SHOW COLUMNS`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.0-en/show-columns.html) and build your query dynamically:

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM yourtable;
```

After you have the column names, you can assemble the `SELECT` statement as described above with multiple `WHERE` conditions.

Be aware however, that this **might result in problems**, as you might end up searching in id columns etc. as well which should probably not be included from a business perspective. Or even worse, you might end up giving information to the end user that he/she is not supposed to have.

Bottom line, think *long and hard* about whether you really cannot find out the names of the columns beforehand.

Comment: Tim,
here i am unsure of how many columns are there in the table and what are column names.

Comment: Have a look at my edit.

Answer (score 0):

There's no specific syntax to do this as far as I am aware. You could build your query like this:-

```
DECLARE @YOURSTRING NVARCHAR(50)
SET @YOURSTRING = 'PARIS'

SELECT * FROM YOURTABLE
WHERE COLUMN1 LIKE '%' + @YOURSTRING + '%'
OR COLUMN2 LIKE '%' + @YOURSTRING + '%'
OR....etc...etc..
```

Comment: Mat, here i am unsure of how many columns are there in the table and what are column names.